# Create a list of dictionaries for every dictionary from list of dictionaries A that is not present in list of dictionaries B

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose there is list of dictionaries called list_a:

```
list_a = [
    {'x' : 1,  'y': 10, 'z': 100},
    {'x' : 2,  'y': 20, 'z': 200},
    {'x' : 3,  'y': 30, 'z': 300},
    {'x' : 4,  'y': 40, 'z': 400},
    {'x' : 5,  'y': 50, 'z': 500}    
]
```

Suppose there is a derivative list that uses the key 'x' from the dictionaries in list_a. This list will be called list_b:

```
list_b = [
    {'x' : 1,  'a': 'cat', 'b': 'apple'},
    {'x' : 3,  'a': 'dog', 'b': 'orange'}
]
```

Notice that list_a and list_b do not have dictionaries full of the same keys. The only equivalent key is 'x'. Otherwise, these dictionaries are entirely different. Also notice that the 'x' key has values 1 and 3 in list_b, not 1 and 2 as an ordered list might have.

How would you produce a list with members of list_a with x values not in list_b?

For example a list called list_c:

```
list_c = [
    {'x' : 2,  'y': 20, 'z': 200},
    {'x' : 4,  'y': 40, 'z': 400},
    {'x' : 5,  'y': 50, 'z': 500}    
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To speed up the lookup make a set of `x` values from `list_b`:

```py
list_b_set = {b['x'] for b in list_b}
```

Then `list_c` can be created with a simple comprehension:

```py
list_c = [a for a in list_a if a['x'] not in list_b_set]
```

Comment: @VisioN--quick addition:

What if I wanted to do a lookup on 'x' and 'y' (assuming that list_b contained y)?

Comment: just made a new question for this follow up in case anyone is interested:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64129453/use-two-keys-to-create-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-a-not-in-b