# Use two keys to create a list of dictionaries in A not in B

Tags: python, dictionary

This is a more complex edit on a previous question. Previously I asked about using only one key, now I would like to learn about how to use two keys:

Suppose there is list of dictionaries called list_a:

```
list_a = [
    {'x' : 1,  'y': 10, 'z': 100},
    {'x' : 1,  'y': 11, 'z': 100},
    {'x' : 1,  'y': 12, 'z': 100},
    {'x' : 2,  'y': 10, 'z': 200},
    {'x' : 2,  'y': 11, 'z': 200},
    {'x' : 2,  'y': 12, 'z': 200}
]
```

Suppose there is a derivative list that uses the key 'x' from the dictionaries in list_a. This list will be called list_b:

```
list_b = [
    {'x' : 1,  'y': 10, 'fruit': 'orange'},
    {'x' : 1,  'y': 12, 'fruit': 'apple'},
    {'x' : 2,  'y': 12, 'fruit': 'banana'}
]
```

Notice that list_a and list_b do not have dictionaries full of the same keys. The only equivalent key is 'x' and 'y'. Otherwise, these dictionaries are entirely different. Also notice that the list_b key values are out of order relative to the original list_a.

How would you produce a list with members of list_a with x,y values not in list_b?

For example a list called list_c:

```
list_c = [

    {'x' : 1,  'y': 11, 'z': 100},
    {'x' : 2,  'y': 10, 'z': 200},
    {'x' : 2,  'y': 11, 'z': 200}
]
```

Previously, someone answered that to do this on one key 'x', it would take:

```
list_b_set = {b['x'] for b in list_b}
list_c = [a for a in list_a if a['x'] not in list_b_set]
```

How can I build on this for 'x' and 'y'?

Comment: It looks like that you would benefit from reading the answer carefully and actually understand it.

Comment: I'm new to python, so I don't understand this syntax too well. It's also difficult to google search about data structures like:

{b['x'] for b in list_b}

I don't even know what they're called let alone what they can do! Can they take [b['x'],b['y']], do I have to do each one separately? I wouldn't know because I don't know how they function. Figuring it out along the way

Comment: What it's called is already stated in the other answer. "comprehension".

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
You seem to be trying to use Stack Overflow for personal tutorial help; this is off-topic.

Comment: awesome thanks for pointing that out--I grabbed the code of the answer and didn't pay too much attention to the words. I've never even seen that word used, so I didn't know to associate it as a proper name. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You've identified the problem: "I don't understand this syntax too well".  You need to spin up on this technique before you can ask a cogent question on the topic.  Bridging that gap is out of scope for this site.

Comment: Thank you! You're right, I felt pretty powerless because as I mentioned, I didn't even know what a comprehension was called (didn't even know it had a proper name). I'll go look more into it.

And you're right, problem solving should be done on my own time, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments for encouraging me to solve this on my own.

For those lost beginners trying to find documentation on :

```
[x for x in y if condition]
```

It's called a **comprehension**. I just started using python and had no idea this thing had a proper name. It's also difficult to google because it is made of symbols and prepositions. Now you know and can look up all the documentation on **comprehensions**!

Here is the solution, it was super simple once I looked up how comprehensions can handle two elements instead of one

```
list_a = [
    {'x' : 1,  'y': 10, 'z': 100},
    {'x' : 1,  'y': 11, 'z': 100},
    {'x' : 1,  'y': 12, 'z': 100},
    {'x' : 2,  'y': 10, 'z': 200},
    {'x' : 2,  'y': 11, 'z': 200},
    {'x' : 2,  'y': 12, 'z': 200}
]

list_b = [
    {'x' : 1,  'y': 10, 'fruit': 'orange'},
    {'x' : 1,  'y': 12, 'fruit': 'apple'},
    {'x' : 2,  'y': 12, 'fruit': 'banana'}
]

list_c = [

    {'x' : 1,  'y': 11, 'z': 100},
    {'x' : 2,  'y': 10, 'z': 200},
    {'x' : 2,  'y': 11, 'z': 200}
]



list_b_set = {(b['x'], b['y']) for b in list_b}
list_c_new = [a for a in list_a if (a['x'],a['y']) not in list_b_set]

list_c_new == list_c
```